# When using docker-compile to build a project, files that are created aren't persisted (Bind Volume | Windows 10)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a an empty project with a Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml.

DockerFile

```
FROM node:12.14.1
RUN mkdir /frontend
WORKDIR /frontend
RUN touch hello.txt
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  frontend:
    build: .
    command: ls
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: .
        target: /frontend
```

When I run `docker-compose build`, the build executes correctly, but the hello.txt file I tried to create is not persisted on my local machine (Windows 10 machine). I need to use a bind volume for development purposes.

Is it possible to persist the file on my local machine during the build process?

Answer (score 0):

With the Docker Compose file version 3.7 you could use the Volume managed by Docker to persist the data of the container.
Please follow the below style.

```
 services:
   frontend:
     build: .
     volumes:
       - 'data:/frontend'
 volumes:
    data:
      driver: local
      name: data
```

Later you can restore the data of this docker volume using a container that bind mounts to this volume and exposes data outside.

Incase one needs to use bind mounts I would say try using absolute path